# Get number of element while iterating through dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

assuming I have a dictionary like:

```
>>> dict = {}
>>> dict[123] = "test1"
>>> dict[456] = "test2"
>>> dict[789] = "test3"
```

and I loop through it like:

```
>>> for bit in dict.keys():
     print bit
```

how can I figure out which element is being processed? I would like to get an output of

```
0
1
2
```

How can I get this?

Please advise!
Thanks!

Comment: What does 0,1,2 represent? `dicts` are unordered...

Comment: You would never be able to get those values with your current example. You would need some kind of an ordered list to get an index for each value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
d = {...}
for i, bit in enumerate(d):
    print i, bit
```

However, bear in mind that `dict` does not guarantee any particular ordering of its keys, so the indexes are probably not meaningful. There are other classes, such as [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) that do guarantee specific ordering of their keys, so you might need to use those.

Also, don't call your variables `dict` as this shadows the [builtin](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Comment: But this information is useless, as the keys of a dictionary are in no particular order.

Comment: `.keys()` in redundant here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Indeed. I've already added a note to this effect.